# Failed API validation-linked in

Tags: web-services, rest

I am using rest API for get slide information using DHC Rest Let. I am using parameter `API_key`, `ts`, `hash`, `slideshow_id`, `slideshow_URL`. When i send request, it is going to hit to specified host URL but while giving response throw following error. For more reference please see
http://www.slideshare.net/developers/documentation

The request body is as follows :

```
www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_user_tags?&api_key=${api_key}&ts=${ts}&hash=${hash}&slideshow_id=${slideshow_id}&slideshow_url=${slideshow_url}
```

Error:

```
<SlideShareServiceError>
<MessageID="1">Failed API validation</Message>
</SlideShareServiceError>
```

Comment: Can you please add the REST request that you tried. Without it it's hard to tell what went wrong.

Comment: By the way, try changing `API_key` to `api_key` in your request. That might be the issue

Comment: with api_key also ,it is showing same error

Comment: The request body is as follows :   
www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_slideshow?slideshow_id=%24%7Bslideshow_id%7D&slideshow_url=%24%7Bslideshow_url%7D&api_key=%24%7Bapi_key%7D&ts=%24%7Bts%7D&hash=%24%7Bhash%7D

Host: www.slideshare.net
slideshow_id: xxxx
slideshow_url: http://www.slideshare.net/kuratowa/metropolis-and-gotham-two-approaches-to-enterprise-site-development
api_key: xxxxx
ts: 1468583104
hash: 4d49b2dd6a7ac6d177d33b9dcb87849227889a84.

Comment: put it into the question itself for a better visibilty